# Finding $\sin t$, if $\frac{2\sec t+3\tan t+5\sin t-7\cos t+5}{2\tan t+3\sec t+5\cos t+7\sin t+8}=2\cos t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Could someone help me solve this trigonometry problem?

> If $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\frac { 2\sec { \theta  } +3\tan { \theta  } +5\sin { \theta  } -7\cos { \theta  } +5 }{ 2\tan { \theta  } +3\sec { \theta  } +5\cos { \theta  } +7\sin { \theta  } +8 } =2\cos { \theta  }$$
> then $\sin { \theta  } =?$

No idea how to solve this. If someone could show  me the first one or two steps to push me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Are you looking for a numerical value for $\sin\theta$.

Comment: yes find sinθ. I have not idea to find it.

Comment: Maybe the value of sinθ in term of Trigonometric function.

Comment: Not too sure if this works, but try expressing everything in terms of $sine$ and $cosine$. Might make things easier to see.

Comment: I'm not sure you can find a numeric value for $\sin\theta$, the equation just looks very complicated.

Comment: $10c^3+14sc^2+23c^2-sc-3s+c-2=0$, where $s$ is $\sin$, $c$ is $\cos$

Answer (score 1):

subtracting $2\cos(x)$ on both sides and find a common denominator we get
$$-{\frac {6\,\cos \left( x \right) \sec \left( x \right) +4\,\cos
 \left( x \right) \tan \left( x \right) +14\,\cos \left( x \right) 
\sin \left( x \right) +10\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}
-2\,\sec \left( x \right) -3\,\tan \left( x \right) -5\,\sin \left( x
 \right) +23\,\cos \left( x \right) -5}{2\,\tan \left( x \right) +3\,
\sec \left( x \right) +5\,\cos \left( x \right) +7\,\sin \left( x
 \right) +8}}
=0$$
the simplified denominator is given by $$-14\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}\sin \left( x \right) 
-10\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{3}+\cos \left( x
 \right) \sin \left( x \right) -23\, \left( \cos \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{2}+3\,\sin \left( x \right) -\cos \left( x \right) +2
=0$$
solving for $\sin(x)$ we obtain
$$\sin(x)=-{\frac {10\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{3}+23\, \left( 
\cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}+\cos \left( x \right) -2}{-3+14\,
 \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}-\cos \left( x \right) }}
$$